# Paypal Sandbox TLS update (400) Bad Request

Tags: java, soap, paypal, paypal-sandbox, tls1.2

Paypal sandbox has been updated to use TLS 1.2 (https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/#tls). Without any changes at my end, I was seeing 'handshake_failure' error.

I've updated the JAVA library that we use as suggested in https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update#paypal-java-sdk-support. I use the legacy 1.x version.

However, PayPal throws PayPalException.

```
[com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.TransactionException] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8082-7) (400)Bad Request:
```

In addition to updating paypal_base.jar (soap), I also use VM option "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" but it does not make any difference.

The paypal endpoint I am using is

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=commit&token=
```

I have tried using the endpoint API Signature -> SOAP -> Sandbox as provided in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/endpoints/ but with no success.

Any suggestions on what else needs to happen?

**UPDATE**

I ran the test application they've provided (TlsCheck.java / jar) and below is the result

```
java "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" -jar TlsCheck.jar 
this client supports TLS 1.2
Failed to connect to TLS 1.2 endpoint
```

Accessing the endpoint tlstest.paypal.com in the browser returns a '400 Bad Request'. Changing the end point to https://tlstest.paypal.com returns "PayPal_Connection_OK" as expected.

I also made a copy of TlsCheck.java (using its default endpoint tlstest.paypal.com) and ran it via my IDE which returned the following (although it was failing to connect initially)

```
this client supports TLS 1.2
Successfully connected to TLS 1.2 endpoint
```

Tried the same with other endpoints like "api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/" but it fails to connect to it stating

```
Failed to connect to TLS 1.2 endpoint
```

**Update**

Turns out my the test using TslCheck.jar failed because the endpoint used in the JAR was "tlscheck.chargify.com" (invalid??) but the source code (from the same location https://github.com/paypal/TLS-update/tree/master/java) used a different endpoint "tlstest.paypal.com" (valid).

**Update**

Despite updating paypal_base.jar I am currently seeing "No service named PayPalAPIAA is available" which eventually leads to 404 Bad Request. Also confirmed that I am using HTTP/1.0 as HTTPSender in the axis library we use defaults to HTTP/1.1. I haven't found a proper way to get around it. I tried following https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/pfwiki.nsf/dx/10022008035400PMWEBRCB.htm to switch to HTTP/1.1. This did not work in my case!!!!

Comment: Not a Java dev, so this might sound stupid - are you _explicitly_ forcing the connection using TLS 1.2 (only)? This was the change I had to do in .Net (client may support more protocols, 1.1 and 1.2 but must _only_ use 1.2 when making calls to Paypal). Hth....

Comment: I still get the same result with with their test application when explicitly setting the protocol to TLSv1.2 (java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -jar TlsCheck.jar).

Answer (score 0):

This works for paypal TLS 1.2 new SHA 256 cert.

*) Download the paypal_cert.pem from paypal sandbox account -> merchant selling tools-> apiaccess.
*) Run openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert_key_pem.txt -inkey cert_key_pem.txt -out paypal_cert.p12

public HashMap httpcall( String methodName, String nvpRequestStr)
    {

```
    String version = "2.3";
    String agent = "Mozilla/4.0";
    String respText = "";
    HashMap nvp = null;

    String encodedData = "METHOD=" + methodName + "&VERSION=" + gv_Version + "&PWD=" + gv_APIPassword + "&USER=" + gv_APIUserName + nvpRequestStr;

    try
    {

            KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

            InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream("/Users/Downloads/paypal_cert.p12");
            keyStore.load(keyInput, "changeit".toCharArray());
            keyInput.close();
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "changeit".toCharArray());

            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSV1.2");
            context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

            URL url = new URL(gv_APIEndpoint);
            HttpsURLConnection conn=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( encodedData.length()) );
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes( encodedData );
            output.flush();
            output.close ();

            // Read input from the input stream.
            DataInputStream  in = new DataInputStream (conn.getInputStream());
            int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
            if ( rc != -1)
            {
                BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( conn.getInputStream()));
                String _line = null;
                while(((_line = is.readLine()) !=null))
                {
                    respText = respText + _line;
                }
                nvp = deformatNVP( respText );
            }
            return nvp;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;
    } catch (CertificateException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {e.printStackTrace(); return null;}
}


public HashMap deformatNVP( String pPayload )
{
    HashMap nvp = new HashMap();
    StringTokenizer stTok = new StringTokenizer( pPayload, "&");
    while (stTok.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        StringTokenizer stInternalTokenizer = new StringTokenizer( stTok.nextToken(), "=");
        if (stInternalTokenizer.countTokens() == 2)
        {
            String key = URLDecoder.decode( stInternalTokenizer.nextToken());
            String value = URLDecoder.decode( stInternalTokenizer.nextToken());
            nvp.put( key.toUpperCase(), value );
        }
    }
    return nvp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. We use CallerServices from paypal_base.jar communicate with PayPal. I'm hoping I don't have to go to this length to resolve this :)

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by simply updating the libraries to use merchantsdk-2.14.117.jar, paypal-core-1.7.0.jar & permissionsskd-2.4.109.jar. The library we were using were quite old and the API calls had to be updated using the new library but the changes were fairly obvious despite the package name changes (*com.paypal.soap.api* to *urn.ebay.api*). Since the HTTP calls were being made by the library, we didn't need to worry about HTTP/1.1 anymore.

I was able to test & verify this against PayPal's sandbox environment.